# Web service authentication

Tags: web-services, security, apache, authentication, apache-axis

I have written my web services using apache axis2. Now I want to make my web services secure to avoid unauthorized access.
Is there any way in apache axis by which we can redirect each web service request to a particular web service ? so that it will do authentication and on successful authentication it will forward the request to respective web service.

Thanks,
Ajinkya.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use Apache Rampart[1] for this. Instead of redirecting to another web service you can use UT (user name token) to authenticate the uses. Using WS-Security is the correct way to secure a web service. This[2] would help you.

If you interested WSO2 AS[3] provides a integrated environment for web service deployment and add security using its GUI. Further since it is based on WSO2 carbon platform you can integrate your user store with WSO2 AS and then authentication is provided out of the box.

[1] http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/rampart/

[2] http://wso2.org/library/240

[3] http://wso2.org/library/application-server

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can you please give some good links as I am not much familiar with this concepts ?